# How to run a Netbeans Android app into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have an android application that is built in netbeans.  Now i want to run it in ADT (Android Developer Tools) or you can say Eclipse.
I do not have Netbeans with me , i just have source code complete.
Please help if anybody have any idea about it.

Comment: Do you have a whole project or just the .apk file?

Comment: @Templar... i have complete source code built in netbeans

Comment: Try import project -> filesystem inside eclipse

Comment: @Templar..its not working...its not changing to eclipse type